# Force <div> elements onto 2 lines

Tags: html, css, css-float

First of all, thanks for taking the time to read this.

I've been working with HTML/CSS for as long as I can remember, but I've come across a problem today which has completely stumped me.

I've got a container , which has a certain number (let's say 8) of dynamically created child divs.  I want the container to display the children on two rows, even if they overflow horizontally.

For example,

```
 ____________
|            |
|[1] [3] [5] | [7]
|[2] [4] [6] | [8]
|____________|
```

Then I'm going to use JS to implement a nice scrolling feature.

However, at the moment, I can only get them to display on one line instead of two, by setting them to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Or scrolling vertically, by using a pretty standard:

```
float: left;
```

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated!

Chris

Comment: What does the html look like and are all children the same width (and is that width fixed)?

Comment: Yes, all children are the same width, which is fixed at 300px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your children elements in rows.

```
.row { height:100px; overflow hidden;} // assuiming 100px is height of a child
.row > .children { height:100px; float:left;}
```

Comment: This would work, but it could be awkward to implement in the situation I have.  I should have mentioned that the most "important" divs are kept further to the left, for example:

<pre>
 ____________
|            |
|[1] [3] [5] | [7]
|[2] [4] [6] | [8]
|____________|
</pre>

I suppose I could do a loop over them to put odd numbers on the top and evens on the bottom.

Thanks.

Comment: assuming the divs all have the sime sizes you could enclose each pair in a div `<div>[1][2]</div></div>[3][4]</div>` and float them to left. Now instead of `.row`s you'll need only one inner div to take care of the overflow.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, can't believe I didn't think of that!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using  the float technique, after the 4th div, place a 5th DIV like so:

```
   div style="clear: both">
```

This 5th div does not count towards your 8 content divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

you can play here ( http://jsfiddle.net/LAymH/2/ )

Works both in IE and FF

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-container">
        <div class="row">Text1</div>
        <div class="row">Text2</div>
        <div class="row">Text3</div>
        <div class="row">Text4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="breaker"></div>

    <div class="row-container">
        <div class="row">Text1</div>
        <div class="row">Text2</div>
        <div class="row">Text3</div>
        <div class="row">Text4</div>
    </div>
</div>

.row {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.breaker{
    clear:both;
}
.row-container{
    width: 600px;
}
.container {
    width: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping through the items in order I think it'd be easier to use columns than rows:

http://jsfiddle.net/ePq6n/

then if you want them in a container something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/ePq6n/1/